# Transaction within IF THEN ELSE doesn't commit

Tags: sql, transactions

In my TSQL script I have an IF THEN ELSE structure that checks if a column already exists.
If not it creates the column and updates it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'columnName'))
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ALTER TABLE tableName
        ADD columnName int NULL
    COMMIT
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        update tableName
        set columnName = [something]
        from 
            [subquery]
    COMMIT
END
```

This doesn't work because the column doesn't exist after the commit.
Why doesn't the COMMIT commit?

Comment: where's your 'THEN' for the IF statement?  Typo?

Comment: Truth is, that pair of BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT blocks do nothing for you. SQL Statements are Atomic (review database ACID properties for more), which essentialy means every individual statement is implcitly "wrapped" within its own transaction. Remove that code, run, and I believe you'll see what AakashM describes.

Comment: Leslie, T-SQL syntax does not require (or support) "THEN".

Comment: @Philip: In real scenario the transactions contain more work, but would be distracting in the example. For example, creating, adding data, making not-null, foreign key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are getting an error at *parse* stage, rather than at *execute* stage. The COMMIT will indeed commit, but the query parser isn't as clever as the query execution engine, and all the *parser* knows is that it can see you referring to `tableName.columnName`, which at *parse* time doesn't exist.

Wrap the whole `update` statement in an `EXEC`:

```
EXEC ('
        update tableName
        set columnName = [something]
        from 
            [subquery]
')
```

and you should be OK. Bear in mind that you will need to double up `'`s within the `'`s of the `EXEC`.

Comment: I'm getting at execute time too.

Comment: Exec-ing indeed works. Sure there must be a better way to get this done then execing everything?

Comment: The best thing is to not have to add table columns on the fly. (We *have* to do it in a project I'm working on now, and it's really, truly, and amazingly awkward.)

Comment: Well, a project that has been running for quite a while now has to be altered to support another column table. This isn't that an exotic request I imagine..

Comment: Ah, if this this is a one-time script used to update an existing system, that's standard.

Comment: Well off course. Do you mean your system is adding (and removing I imagine) columns at runtime on regular basis?